# Open VBA userform won't let me edit other Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a really weird problem. While working with userforms in an Excel file, I can't edit or scroll other Excel files, that have nothing to do with the userform. Or in general, other Excel files are kind of laggy. As soon as I close the form, I can edit the other Excel files again.

Is this a hardware problem (not enough ram/ cpu power?) or does it have something to do with settings of the userform itself?

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: How are you showing the userform? In Modal? If yes then try this `Frm.Show vbModeless`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/show-method